# IQkeyboardManager is not working properly on iOS 11 objective-c

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, ios11, iqkeyboardmanager

In iOS 11, `IQkeyboardManager` is not working properly: the buttons on the toolbar of the keyboard are not shown. It's just an empty toolbar. I'm using Objective-C for the project.

[image]

Comment: Did you update to the latest version?

Comment: I didn't found any update for objective-c of the same. @rckoenes

Comment: You will need to update to the swift version then, there seem to be a fix in the repo. You can mix Obj-c and Swift so this should not be an issue.

Comment: Actually I don't want to update my project to swift or the mix for now.. is there any alternate approach. otherwise this would be my last priority to use both lang. in my project @rckoenes

Comment: Findout what they fixed and fix it yourself.

Comment: @rckoenes the swift one is also not working on my objective-c code

Answer (score 0):

use pod update, as it was fixed in 5.0.4

[image]